# Why is $\pi(\sigma)$ a well defined mapping $V^{\otimes n} \to V^{\otimes n}$?

Tags: representation-theory, tensor-products

Given an $R$-module V, where $R$ is a commutative ring (we even assume $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subring, though I don't think that's required for my particular question), we wish to view the wedge product $V^{\wedge n}$ as a submodule of $V^{\otimes n}$ rather than as a quotient. In attempting to accomplish this, we define a mapping $\pi\colon S_n\to \operatorname{End}_R(V^{\otimes n})$ by

$\pi(\sigma)(\sum_{i=1}^k r_iv_{i1}\otimes v_{i2}\cdots \otimes v_{in}) = \sum_{i=1}^kr_i v_{i\sigma^{-1}(1)}\otimes v_{i\sigma^{-1}(2)}\cdots \otimes v_{i\sigma^{-1}(n)}$.

I fail to see why $\pi(\sigma)$ is a well defined mapping $V^{\otimes n}\to V^{\otimes n}$. How would I show that? Elements of $V^{\wedge n}$ can typically be written as a linear combination of pure tensors in more than one way. How does one show that whichever linear combination one chooses, the value of the RHS is always the same?

Comment: @coiso Aren't there multiple ways of representing an element of $V^{\otimes n}$, given that the elements are cosets? How do we make sure that our particular choice of representative doesn't affect the value of the right hand side?

Comment: @coiso No, that's exactly my question.

Comment: @coiso I fixed numerous things. My question is why it's well defined. You can restrict to elements of the form $v_1\otimes\cdots \otimes v_n$ if you like.

Comment: If you define $V^{\otimes n}$ to be a quotient of the free vector space on $V^n$, you can first define $\pi(\sigma)$ on the free vector space, show the subspace being quotient'd by is stable, hence $\pi(\sigma)$ is defined on the quotient, and has the given effect on simple tensors. In other words, applying $\pi(\sigma)$ to both sides of the relations (characterizing the multilinearity of the $\otimes$ symbol) yields another valid relation.

Comment: @coiso Could you be more explicit? I know of the lemma saying that if $T: V\to W$ is $R$-linear and $S$ is a submodule of $V$, then the mapping $\overline{T}: V/S\to W$ given by $\overline{T}(x+S) = T(x)$ is well defined and linear. I don't see how to use that here though, since I want to define $\pi$ on $S_n$ which certainly isn't a quotient...

Comment: You wanted to show $\pi(\sigma)$ is well-defined for each $\sigma\in S_n$. Each $\pi(\sigma)$ you want to be a linear operator on $V^{\otimes n}$, which you're defining (I assume) as a quotient of the free vector space on the underlying set of $V^n$. Once you know each $\pi(\sigma)$ exists, then $\pi$ itself is just the map $S_n\to{\rm GL}(V^{\otimes n}):\sigma\mapsto\pi(\sigma)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $\sigma \in S_n$. Define a map $V^n\to V^{\otimes n}$ via $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)\mapsto v_{\sigma^{-1}(1)} \otimes \ldots \otimes v_{\sigma^{-1}(n)}$.

Now check that this is multilinear and hence induces by the universal property of tensor products a well-defined linear map $V^{\otimes n}\to V^{\otimes n}$ which is the map $\pi(\sigma)$ that you want.

(If you only know the universal property of tensor products with two factors, use induction to generalize it to $n$ factors.)

Comment: Thank you. This, in addition to the lemma I stated in the comments (which, by the way, should include the extra hypothesis $T(S) = \{0\}$) did the trick.

Comment: Now I'm stuck on showing that it's a group homomorphism. I'm thinking it would suffice to show that given permutations $\sigma$ and $\tau$, one has $v_{\sigma^{-1}(\tau^{-1}(1))}\otimes\cdots\otimes v_{(\sigma^{-1}(\tau^{-1}(n))} = v_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes v_{\sigma^{-1}(n)}+v_{\tau^{-1}(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes v_{\tau^{-1}(n)}$. Any ideas?

Comment: @SimonSMN no, you need to show that $\pi(\sigma \tau)=\pi(\sigma) \circ \pi(\tau)$

Comment: But how is $\operatorname{End}_R(V^{\otimes n})$ then a group w r t composition? Not every element in it has an inverse, does it?

Comment: It's not a group. You're checking for a monoid homomorphism. The image is then contained in the group of automorphisms

Comment: Oh, okay. It actually says group homomorphism in the lecture notes by the lecturer. That'd be a typo, then? It also says pi is an action.

Comment: @SimonSMN If you consider the automorphisms as codomain, then it's a group homomorphism. Otherwise, it's an insignificant inaccuracy, yeah

Comment: I don't see how the image of pi is contained in the automorphism group though. Pi gives us a homomorphism, which needn't be invertible.

Comment: It's a general phenomenon: if $G$ is a group and $M$ is a monoid and $f:G\to M$ is a monoid homomorphism, then every element in the image of $f$ is invertible and hence we obtain a group homomorphism $G\to M^\times$, where $M^\times $ is the group of invertible elements of $M$

Comment: Oh yes, that's right. Thank you!

Comment: On second thought, the universal property is sufficient. So your answer is complete. Thought I'd write this in case someone revisits this question.